# DateTime.ParseExact AM/PM indicator lowercase

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

Consider the following string...

```
var myString = "11/05/2015 01:04:16 p.m."
```

Can I execute DateTime.ParseExact on this string without forcing the string uppercase?  The am/pm indicator is giving me grief, and failing to parse because it is lowercase.  I have a static class with constants for format strings.  Is there a format token for specifying lowercase am/pm indicator?

**Format Strings**

```
namespace myProgram
{
    public static class MyFormatStrings
    {
        public const string MyDateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss t\\.\\M\\.";
    }
}
```

**Logic to parse**

```
namespace myProgram
{
    public static class MyProgram
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            var myStringDateValue = "11/05/2015 01:04:16 p.m.";
            var result = DateTime.ParseExact(myStringDateValue, MyFormatStrings.MyDateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because am and pm aren't typically a.m. and p.m.? Try just replacing the p.m. and a.m. with am or pm (or just remove all the .'s in the input string).

Comment: @Ron - I am constrained on input.  I must accept the string in the format shown above.  Looking to keep it simple with a format string and no manipulation of original input string.

Comment: You couldn't do something like (DateTime.ParseExact(myStringDateValue.Replace(".", ""), ...) ? I'm not sure date-time format strings can specify .'s in the string, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ttSpecifier

Comment: @Ron - as I understand it, the format token 't' allows a single character for the AM/PM indicator, but the AM/PM indicator ('A', or 'P') must be uppercase.  If using the format token 'tt' instead, then the AM/PM indicator must be two characters wide ('AM', or 'PM') but can be either upper or lower case.

Comment: using the format string of "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" and what I posted above, I was able to run your code and get a valid date, without changing case. Maybe add a parse constant to your format strings class.

Comment: are you familiar with the .ToLower() method.. you can do that  using the .ToString Method when working with dates.. I will post an example

Comment: @Ron - the format string you specify does not work for the date I present in the OP.

Comment: @MethodMan - ToLower() will not work with a single char AM/PM indicator.  Because the original input string has AM/PM indicator with/including periods I assume I must use the format token 't' instead of 'tt' which then requires the AM/PM indicator to be uppercase.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a code editor and just changed the format string (not the date string value you used) and it worked fine... The only other option is to create your own CultureInfo as described in one of your answers, but you still have to change the format string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the AMDesignator / PMDesignator of the DateFormatInfo in your culture.

This information is ReadOnly so, you must create your own Culture:

I also changed the `MyDateTimeFormat` format so it could work:

```
    public class MyCultureInfo : CultureInfo
    {
        public MyCultureInfo():base(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Name)
        {
        }
        public override DateTimeFormatInfo DateTimeFormat
        {
            get
            {
                DateTimeFormatInfo myDateTimeFormatInfo = base.DateTimeFormat;
                myDateTimeFormatInfo.PMDesignator = "p.m.";
                myDateTimeFormatInfo.AMDesignator = "a.m.";
                return myDateTimeFormatInfo;
            }
            set
            {
                base.DateTimeFormat = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public static class MyFormat
    {
        public const string MyDateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
    }
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myStringDateValue = "11/05/2015 01:04:16 p.m.";
        var result = DateTime.ParseExact(myStringDateValue, MyFormat.MyDateTimeFormat, new MyCultureInfo());
    }
```

Comment: I was hoping for a quick format string, but this works.  This is a pretty cool answer too - never knew I could define a custom culture.

Comment: Me neither, until I see your question ;)